# Prisma how to update many rows with different data

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, prisma

what is the best way to update many records with different data ?
I'm doing it like this

```
const updateBody = JSON.parse(req.body);

      try {
        for (let object of updateBody) {
          await prisma.comissions.upsert({
            where: {
              producer: object.producer,
            },
            update: {
              rate: object.rate,
            },
            create: object,
          });
        }
```

I'm being able to update it, but it's taking a really long time to do so. I'm aware of `transaction`, but i'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In Prisma transaction query is used in two ways.

**Sequential operations:** Pass an array of Prisma Client queries to be executed sequentially inside of a transaction.

**Interactive transactions:** Pass a function that can contain user code including Prisma Client queries, non-Prisma code, and other control flow to be executed in a transaction.

In our case we should use the interactive transaction, Because it contain user code, To use the callback function in the Prisma transaction, we need to add a preview feature to the Prisma.schema file

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["interactiveTransactions"]
}
```

```
prisma.$transaction(async(prisma) => {
  try {
        for (let object of updateBody) {
          await prisma.comissions.upsert({
            where: {
              producer: object.producer,
            },
            update: {
              rate: object.rate,
            },
            create: object,
          });
        }
});
```